# Multiple if's and read lines ignored

Tags: bash

I have written a script containing various user queries and conditions. First, I want the user to be asked if the changelog should be displayed. Then the user is asked if he should do the update. But here is the problem, after the first condition and the display of the changelog, the next query is simply skipped. Why is that?

```sh
    if version_gt $serverversion $version; then
      echo -e "\e[34m#########################################################"
      echo -e "\e[34mThere is a new version. Do you want to see the Changelog?"
      echo -e "\e[34m#########################################################"
      read -p "Yes(y)/No(n) " -n 1 -r changelog

      if [[ $changelog =~ ^[Yy]$ ]]
      then
        curl --silent "$changelogurl"
      fi

      echo -e "\e[34m#########################################################"
      echo -e "\e[34mDo you want to update?"
      echo -e "\e[34m#########################################################"
      read -p "Yes(y)/No(n) " -n 1 -r update

      if [[ $update =~ ^[Yy]$ ]]
      then
        echo -e "\e[32m#########################################################"
        echo -e "\e[32mI am updating myself..."
        echo -e "\e[32m#########################################################"
        sleep 4

        curl --silent "$bashlyurl" > bashlyblog.sh
        curl --silent "$templateurl" > template.html  

        echo -e "\e[32m#########################################################"
        echo -e "\e[32mUpdate done. Restart..."
        echo -e "\e[32m#########################################################"
        /bin/bash bashlyblog.sh
        exit 1
      fi
fi
```

Answer (score 4):

You might be typing the letter `y` and pressing `Enter` key whereas your script moves on as soon as you've typed `y`, since you added `-n 1` to your `read` command.
Try typing `y` without pressing `Enter` key, or removing `-n 1` if you'd rather press key `Enter`.